# Is it possible to display a non-existent url using an htacess file

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

Not sure if this is possible.  I have a .html file in a sub-directory. I want to find a way to set it up, using HTACCESS I imagine, to display an alternate URL when that file/directory is accessed.

So, if the inbound URL is something like http://example.com/target-directory/file.html how can I use HTACCESS to force the browser to display http://renamedURL.com/ instead.

Possible? Or am I just a crazy-coo-coo dreamer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^target-directory/file.html$ http://renamedURL.com/ [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+target-directory/file\.html[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://renamedURL.com/ [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^/?$ /target-directory/file.html [L]
```